# How to integrate Bootstrap with Eliom?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, ocaml, ocsigen

I am trying to use Bootstrap within the Eliom framework but I cannot figure out how to use some of the html attributes correctly. Take for example the following code from the bootstrap website (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups):

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

I cannot figure out how to replicate the attributes `role` and `aria-label` in Eliom. They are not listed under `type base_attributes`, `type button_attrib` or `type common` (http://ocsigen.org/tyxml/3.4/api/Html5_types#TYPEcommon). Can the above code be replicated in Eliom?

Comment: Also not familiar with Eliom, but most frameworks don't **force** you to use their markup. I know with Laravel and CakePHP, you can use their `Form::create` helper classes to make forms, or you can code it manually as `<form method="..." action="...">...</form>`. Are you unable to do this is Eliom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `role` and `aria-...` attributes are used to give hints to enhance accessibility for people with disabilities (see [this ARIA article at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA)). Depending on the accessibility requirements you must decide if you need them, Bootstrap's styling and JavaScript components aren't dependent on them.

Looking at the [Ocsigen FAQ](http://ocsigen.org/faq) (look for "Some HTML5 element or attribute is missing. What can I do?") it seems that if you use the TyXML library you can use the low unsafe interface [Html5_sigs.​T.​Unsafe](http://ocsigen.org/tyxml/dev/api/Html5_sigs.T.Unsafe). But frankly I don't know anything about Eliom.

Answer (score 3):

A binding was started [here](https://github.com/a-tsioh/Bootliom).

As ckuijjer said, the Unsafe module is the right way to add non-existent attributes/elements. The one that are missing should be contributed to tyxml, of course. :)